# ASUS X555LJ RAM Upgrade (8 GB -> 12 GB)

Tags: windows-8, laptop, memory, asus-laptop, ramdisk

I have an ASUS X555LJ laptop with 4 GB of RAM on board and 4 GB of RAM removable, both of them DDR3L SODIMM 1600. ASUS suggested me to replace the 4 GB removable one with a bank of 8 GB after I asked them how to increase the speed of my laptop. So I bought the CT102464BF160B of Crucial at [this](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/x555lj/CT7158634) link. It has the same specifications of my current removable RAM and I also ran the Crucial Compatibility Tool to ensure the compatibility.
However, after replacing the 4 GB bank with the 8 GB bank, the laptop doesn't power on. What's the problem?

I'm getting angry. Everyone say that CT102464BF160B is full compatible with my X555LJ but the laptop doesn't power on.

EDIT 1

After placing the old 4 GB RAM back to the slot, the laptop turns on. The number part of the current RAM is M471B5173DB0-YK0.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited the question. Please, check.

Answer (score 0):

While spec says that the Laptop in question accepts max 8GB RAM module, this is not always written in stone. Several times already i was able to upgrade laptops in RAM department with double the max specced size (manual said 2x 4GB, machine worked well and stable with 2x8GB), but it's basically trial and error. The issue is that while nominally and in 99% of cases when you're buying a module from well-known vendor (like Crucial) the compatibility tool works fine, however I've seen first hand that there can be some sort of hardware incompatibility.

So, module purchased should work fine. however, usually when there is memory issue the laptop should power up and then report error (usually beep code).

If laptop is not powering up at all then it is equipped with very poor hardware and/or BIOS. And also there are 3 possibilities:

1. Incompatible memory. Let's say we ruled it out, but I would still test it with different 8GB module, if possible.
2. Faulty memory module. Do you have access to another machine where you can test the purchased Crucial memory? This would be 1st step
3. Faulty memory slot. very unlikely, since it's working with older memory module, but possible. Do you have access to another 4GB memory stick to test?

I am aware that all the options above require access to excess hardware, but from my experience there is no way around that. Best option for that is a computer repair shop, where you can test your machine with all combinations above. Yes, it may involve some fee...

So, if you'll do all the above then if option 1 is positive (your 8GB module is fine), option 2 is also positive (again, your 8GB is fine) and option 3 is passed also (accepts other 4GB), then issue is with the laptop. IIRC >4GB module requires more pathways to the CPU memory controller, so either they're lying that laptop accepts 8GB modules or motherboard is faulty.

But I admit that last would be first time I've even heard about something like it

Comment: so why did Asus and Crucial say that the module I purchased is officially compatible?

Comment: If their original memory module was DDR3 or DDR3L compatible, why was a DDRL3L only module unsupported?  Are you sure about this answer?

Comment: @Ramhound - I wanted to include the links and today I've landed on a different page. Or I had visual impairment and/or seen things. System is DDR3L compatible. So half of my answer is wrong, editing.

Comment: @FabioTuccillo see edited answer.

Comment: @AcePL so definitely what would you do if you were me?

Comment: @FabioTuccillo - Return the memory as defective and get a replacement module.

Comment: @Ramhound this one should work? It has the same part number... https://www.amazon.it/Samsung-Memoria-DDR3-SO-DIMM-1600MHz/dp/B00KEAEX54?th=1

Comment: I cannot read Italian.  When I suggested getting a replacement, I mean get the same module, the one you have simply is defective.

Comment: @FabioTuccillo I would test. But I can do that  because i have available parts and computers that I know are working. In your shoes? Ramhound's comment is good - return module as defective and order replacement. Model you bought is adequate, ask for replacement.